# When we say f(x)->l as x->c then how c becomes a limit point of the domain of defination of f.

Tags: analysis

I think that if c be an isolated point of the domain of f then continuity of c does not imply existence of the limit of f at c.Is it the only cause?

Answer (score 0):

since $c$ is an isolated point then there is $\delta‎‎$ that $(c-\delta‎‎, c+\delta‎‎)$ has only $c$. Now suppose ‎$\epsilon$ has given  There are no points in the domain of f such that $0<|x−c|<\delta$, thus use the logic relations $p\Rightarrow q$ that when p is false realtion is true(If the hypothesis of a statement is false then the statement is true)